# how to submit JSON Array to Database Table in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4, multidimensional-array

Here is JSON Code to post that array to GetBulk Method:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    var array = [
        {
            StudentRecordId: 1,
            Name: "Amit",
            Marks: 11,
            Grade: "A"
        },
        {
            StudentRecordId: 2,
            Name: "Abhishek",
            Marks: 12,
            Grade: "A"
        },
        {
            StudentRecordId: 3,
            Name: "Vipin",
            Marks: 13,
            Grade: "A"
        }
    ]

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Home/GetBulk",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional:true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: array }),
        traditional: true,//"feedGraphId=10696",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("j= " + result.studentRecord);                 
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is method of my controller:

```
//to recieve array from json and post values to student record table
public JsonResult GetBulk(List<StudentRecord> models)
{
    StudentRecord studentRecords = new StudentRecord();

    foreach(var item in models)
    {
        studentRecords.Name = item.Name;
        studentRecords.Marks = item.Marks;
        studentRecords.Grade = item.Grade;
        db.StudentRecords.Add(studentRecords);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    var c = db.StudentRecords.ToList();
    return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class StudentRecord
{
    public long StudentRecordId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

So then how can I submit my values to a table using this json array?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to set the `contentType` of your AJAX request and also sent incorrect JSON payload (your server expects an array but you sent it as an object: `{"data":[...]}`):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/GetBulk',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(array),
    success: function (result) {
        alert("j= " + result.studentRecord);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Other things you may notice in my code:

- gotten rid of the `dataType: 'json'` -> it's unnecessary if the server sets the correct Content-Type response header (which it will if you return a Json result). In this case jQuery will use this response header to know how to process the response data
- gotten rid of the `traditional: true` parameter -> it's useless when you are sending a JSON request which is what you are doing here
- replaced `JSON.stringify({ data: array })` with `JSON.stringify(array)` because with the first your data will be send like this: `{ "data": [...] }` whereas your server expects an `List<StudentRecord>` so the payload should look like this: `[...]`

Comment: Shouldn't the data be `JSON.stringify({ models: arrary })` so the model binder will be able to match the action method parameter with the value from the request?

Comment: @Darin thanks a lot its work for me...can i have your mail so that i can ask my problem there